# Compare latitude and longitude in a rectangle area (no distance)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with users, defined with a latitude and longitude in a database (MySQL) and I extract the information with a PHP script.

An app on mobile allows me to draw a rectangle, and send me the coordinates of the top left point, and the coordinates of the bottom right point.

How can I compare the latitudes and longitudes to find which user is in the rectangle? I found many solutions with a circle and distances, but it doesn't fit my needs...

My current query, wrong!:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE latitude BETWEEN ".$latitudeTopLeft." AND ".$latitudeBottomRight." AND longitude BETWEEN ".$longitudeTopLeft." AND ".$longitudeBottomRight.";
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks...

Comment: What does a rectangle on a curved surface look like?

Comment: Your query its fine.. change order between lat because latitudeBottonRight < latitudeTopLeft (horizontal line) => latitude BETWEEN ".$latitudeBottomRight." AND ".$latitudeTopLeft."

Comment: Names `longitudeTopLeft` are a bit odd. Is it just a naming quirk? Usually longitude or latitude is either the top/bottom or left/right coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has some basic spatial extensions (see spatial extensions). This allows you to store lat/long points as point records. Using this, you could create selections using the '[minimum bounding rectangle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html)'.

But since you already have an existing structure, you'll might need to work with between.

```
$LAT1 = min($latitudeTopLeft, $latitudeBottomRight);
$LAT2 = max($latitudeTopLeft, $latitudeBottomRight);

$LON1 = min($longitudeTopLeft, $longitudeBottomRight);
$LON2 = max($longitudeTopLeft, $longitudeBottomRight);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE latitude BETWEEN '.$LAT1.' AND '.$LAT2.' AND longitude BETWEEN '.$LON1.' AND '.$LON2.';
```